# Removing diamonds from a 14 karat gold ring with acid

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment, safety

I have a 14 karat gold ring with diamonds. I want to weaken the metal (to get the diamonds out without damaging them).

If I dip the ring in sulfuric acid, will I be able to dissolve the base metal in the alloy leaving the gold in place?

Comment: Visit a jeweler to open the mounting.  Gold is inert to any chemistry you can safely assemble.  Tapping a diamond parallel to [111] crystal orientation will spall off triangular pieces.

Comment: there is a solution aqua regia which can dissolve gold but i don't know whether it will dissolve diamond or might ... It's better to ask jeweller

Comment: Jewelers have tools to do this as @UncleAl suggests. Gold is fairly inert (even 14 carat), and the diamond is more reactive with many things.

Comment: Surely the gold alloy of the ring is far more mechanically weak than the diamond (given diamond is 10 on the Mohs scale) so you could just use needle-nose pliers to open out the mounting without risking the diamond?

Comment: It doesn't have a mounting that can be got at with pliars

Comment: If it is a gold alloy, I suspect you can bend the entire ring with a small g-clamp and the diamond may pop out of its fitting. There is also the possibility that the diamond is in someway soldered to the base of the fitting, in which event heating would release it (even if not, gold melts a good bit earlier than diamond)

Comment: Can the attachments be ground with a Dremel if you can't reach them with pliers? Dimond does not solder or braze , etc. Aqua regia is a bad idea for an armature.

Answer (score 3):

I think that asking a jeweler is the best thing to do because gold is not something to throw away. However talking about the chemical concern, sulfuric acid can't oxidize gold, if the base metal (you should specify where and how it is) is iron theoretically you will be able to dissolve it with sulfuric acid:
$$\ce{Fe + H2SO4 ->FeSO4 + H2 ^}$$

Something similar can happen with copper and tin but I think that temperature of the acid is a determinant parameter for these reactions.

If the base metal is inside the alloy is quite unlikely that you can affect it because gold is not a porous material, so you can only interact with the superficial layer.